# React Passport Auth with Express Localhost issue with cors() not enabling

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, axios

I'm looking to get the React front end to hit a route on my Express backend, which will allow redirect to the github auth, and then when successful, return auth results so i can save and use them in the front end. My problem is thus:

I have a React front end (:3333) with a button.

```
<Button
     onClick={this.login.bind(this)}
     label={"Login with github"}
     />
```

That runs axios to get to the backend (:3000) route to login with Passport(-github to be exact).

```
 axios.get("http://localhost:3000/login/github")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

Auth works perfectly when just using the backend and buttons in express, but i want to use the React front end, and hit these points at the backend to Auth at the front. A common thing? Yes.

Express backend app.js (server.js) looks mostly like this (rm a little for ease):

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');
var passport = require('passport');
var Strategy = require('passport-github').Strategy;

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.use(cors());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

passport.use(new Strategy({
        clientID: 'correct id',
        clientSecret: 'correct secret id',
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/login/github/return'
    },

passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    cb(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, cb) {
    cb(null, obj);
});

// Initialize Passport and restore authentication state, if any, from the SESH
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

And the routes defined. /login is just a page with a link to login/github which is the one that does the redirects for Auth and then of course returns at /login/github/return

```
// Define routes.
app.get('/',
    function(req, res) {
        res.render('home', { user: req.user });

    });

app.get('/login',
    function(req, res){
        res.render('login');
    });

app.get('/login/github', cors(),
    passport.authenticate('github'));

app.get('/login/github/return', cors(),
    passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Now when in React, (from running both express and react on localhost) and hitting the /login/github endpoint returns the XMLHttpRequest error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fgithub%2Freturn&client_id=96e894aef351c46acd2e. 
`Redirect from 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fgithub%2Freturn&client_id=96e894aef351c46acd2e'` 
to 'https://github.com/login?client_id=96e894aef351c46acd2e&return_to=%2Flogin%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3D96e894aef351c46acd2e%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Flogin%252Fgithub%252Freturn%26response_type%3Dcode' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'd have thought that adding in `app.use(cors());`  at the start would be enough. What am I missing?

Here is a github repo i made to test out auth and it coincidentally replicated this problem exactly. https://github.com/croft1/passport-react-express-auth-demo